# What algorithm should I use for multiple object overall shortest path finding?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to find what algorithm should I use to find the overall shortest path when moving from a square with n nodes on its perimeter to a circle with n nodes on its perimeter in a 3D space.

I know I need to use the formula  $d = \sqrt{(x_{c}-x_{s})²+(y_{c}-y_{s})²+(z_{c}-z_{s})²}$ to find the length of the path between one node of the square and one node of the circle but for 8 nodes there are $8! = 40320$ combinations and for 100 nodes there are $100! = 9.332622e157$ combinations.

So brute-forcing this problem is not an option.

What algorithm would you recommend to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is essentially the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem): given two finite sets $A$ and $B$ of the same size and a distance function $d \colon A \times B \to {\mathbb R}_{\geq 0}$, find a bijection $\pi \colon A \to B$ that minimizes $\sum_{a \in A} d(a, \pi(a))$. Scanning that page, it seems easiest to solve this using standard [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me what type of problem it is.